# Show modal dialog only on onbeforeunload

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog, onbeforeunload

I am trying to show a modal dialog when user clicks on browser close button. I tried

```
var linkclicked = false;
links = document.getElementsByTagName("html")
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function () {
        linkclicked = true;
    }
}

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (linkclicked == false) {
        $("#saveAsDraft").modal("toggle");
       // return "Leave Page?";
    }
};
```

it shows modal dialog and quits it and closes browser without waiting for user input.

Modal Dialog

```
 <div id="saveAsDraft" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title brit-model-title">
                    Enter  description 
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="description" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-submit-idea pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" ng-disabled="description == null || description.length === 0" ng-click="saveDraftToServer(false)">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>&nbsp;OK
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modal dialog works fine when placed on button or any link inside html